# How to measure the amount of time taken to do any kind of operation inside apps such as Maya, Creo Parametric, Adobe Premier, etc

Tags: maya, autodesk, cad, adobe-premiere, lightroom

I want to measure the amount of time taken to do any kind of operation inside apps such as Creo Parametric 5.0, Adobe Premiere Pro, Maya, Adobe Creative, Lightroom CC or any other design app

The idea is to measure the performance (time taken per operation) to catch performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your library of action, you can create a decorator that log and time any actions so you can monitor whats going on

Comment: Thank you @DrWeeny
I need something from the app side or a generic solution. Do these apps have a logger that has state events to denote completion of an operation? I can grab those event details from the log file and log the time.

Comment: there is no united workflow between these softwares. You will have to create a library of command for each that evaluates things mostly with timeIt wraped around internal functions. In maya you could want to evaluate some node with : https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/evaluationManager.html

Answer (score 0):

A method which is hacky and time consuming but generic (even for softwares not providing (good) scripting), could be to record your screen at high speed (such as 60 fps). Then you look at the frames to count the frames between giving the order (click, enter key) and the result (updated display).

The precision will be in the order of 1 / recording frequency (16 ms if recording at 60 fps). A drawback is that you are likely to measure the time of more than just the operation you are interested in, for instance if you want to bench the loading of a file, you will also measure the time it took to render it after (which may/should be negligible).

I was able to apply this method using https://github.com/SerpentAI/D3DShot (increase the framebuffer size which by default last 1 second). Note that the frame numbers when exporting to files are going backward in time.

It may be possible to make this method less hacky by using computer vision algorithms to not have to count frames manually.